# Multiple filter using grep and subset in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to create a filter to remove lines from a dataset using grep and subset together.

Sample dataset:

```
id <- 1:10
problem <- c("a" , "b", "c", "d", "a","b","c","a", "b", "a")
solution1 <- c("eat", "sleep", "drink", "play", "sleep", "play", "play", "drink", "play", "eat")
solution2 <- c("read", "read", "eat", "drink", "eat", "sleep", "eat", "read", "eat", "play")
df <- c(id, problem, solution1, solution2)
```

I'm trying to remove those rows with problem "a" and have "eat" in either solution1 or solution2.

The result is that it should remove id 1, 5 and 10.

I have tried using:

```
df <- subset(df, problem=="a" & !(grepl("eat", df)))
```

and

```
df <- df[!grepl("eat", df) & grepl("a", df$problem)]
```

Can't seem to find a similar solution on StackOverflow or on other websites I Googled.

Would appreciate if anyone can help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you want a dataframe, you should use data.frame, not c:

```
df <- data.frame(id, problem, solution1, solution2)
```

Then you can subset like this for instance (no need to use subset per se)

```
df2 <- df[!(grepl("a", df$problem) & 
           (grepl("eat", df$solution1) |
            grepl("eat", solution2))),]

#   id problem solution1 solution2
# 2  2       b     sleep      read
# 3  3       c     drink       eat
# 4  4       d      play     drink
# 6  6       b      play     sleep
# 7  7       c      play       eat
# 8  8       a     drink      read
# 9  9       b      play       eat
```

Comment: ok thanks. will do.. first time using this. but same question to the other poster, the solution works well on this sample data, but when i apply it to my read dataset, your solution gives me this result: Error: unexpected ',' in:
"              (grepl("Digoxin", data$Med_7_Name |
                 grepl("Digoxin", data$Med_8_Name))),"  The Digoxin is supposed to be like the eat and Med_7_Name is the solution1. Is there anything i should be aware of?

Comment: A closing parenthesis is missing after data$Med_7_Name

Comment: ok. closed it and i got the same result as for A Val's solution. the same number of rows as the initial df remain. i guess something went wrong as i translated this to the sample data for this site. thanks anyway... adopted your answer since you posted first.

Comment: You might need to play a little with the grepl function if you don't get the results you intend. You can also post your unsuccessful attemps as an edit to your original post, no problem there!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
df <- df[!(df$problem %in% "a" & (df$solution1 %in% "eat" | df$solution2 %in% "eat")),]

#   id problem solution1 solution2
# 2  2       b     sleep      read
# 3  3       c     drink       eat
# 4  4       d      play     drink
# 6  6       b      play     sleep
# 7  7       c      play       eat
# 8  8       a     drink      read
# 9  9       b      play       eat
```

regex is not really necessary here if you compare exact strings. Using `%in%` for subsetting will save you alot of time, because it compares vectors. e.g. instead of `"a"` there could have been `c("a", "b", "c")` etc.

Comment: thanks! your solution works well too. however when i try applying both your solution to my real dataset, the row that are meant to be filtered don't get removed. i still get a df with the same number of rows. is there anything that i'm not doing correctly or should be aware of?

Comment: Most likely problem is within name of data frame or column names, make sure you adapt the code to your dataset accordingly. And.. brackets. They are often source of typos.

Comment: thanks. i double checked the names and even used column number. the variable is "character" too. stuck! anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I can't solve problems that I can't see. This is how StackExchange works. You provide problem and example, we provide solution to your example. Both mine and Dominics answers solve the problem...

Comment: totally agree with you. ok thanks for your help anyway!